# my posts are being downvoted without any reason

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Today, I'm facing strange thing.

From morning, someone is down-voting my posts 
(even months earlier posts), without leaving any comment specifying any reason.

at first i thought that, it my posts were not good in quality so I deleted couple of them. but now i m getting worried.

for example,

see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50878979/3901530

two older posts I have deleted and one question does have valid answer so i let it be as it is.

What should i do in such case?

Comment: then if i m in such condition, what should i do instead of asking help here ?

Comment: If downvotes are suspicious they will get reverted back ... But I see only 3 downvotes ... you think it's too much? you are getting more for this question

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala I'm sorry I didn't get what you mean ? i find it suspensions because there are suddenly so many of them in short time.

Comment: *so many* == 3 ? ... *short time* == 8h? or 20min?

Comment: The 2 posts you link here are 2 hours old or less... When else would they have been downvoted?

Comment: 6 (or 7) in 8h.. it was never so frequent, and those too 3 of them was on months ago's post..

Comment: If you got an upvote on a 3 month old post, you will find it strange and you will ask why? I don't think so ...

Comment: I have deleted them, if you can see my deleted posts

Comment: No one but you can find them. If you link them here, anyone with 10K rep or more can see. But they have no way to get the links themselves

Comment: @TemaniAfif I never got upvotes for that old post.. so i dont know how i would react on that to be honest.

Comment: @Amit I saw 3 downvotes in 8 hours, BEFORE YOU POSTED ON META, which is not an abuse at all. Let's see, now that you brought attention to your already downvoted (not so great maybe?) answer, there's a lot more downvotes comming... I guess you won't bring this on meta again. Sorry you were victim of meta effect...

Comment: @AntoinePelletier honestly i m not after number of downvotes.. it's okay to get downvotes on poor post..  but what should i do if downvotes are there without any reasoning.

Comment: you should move one and don't pay attention because you can do nothing

Comment: @Amit True thought, commenting is encouraged when downvoting, but it's not forced, some voters would rater not identify themselves so they don't have to deal with OP arguing. I don't say you would argue, but some won't take this chance

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah i guess you are making sense here. thanks !

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hardly believe the same person has downvoted your posts because of the time difference.

[image]

You have got 2 downvotes for the first post (clearly not from the same person), and two for other two posts with a time gap of more than 7 hours and **none of the above posts have got any upvotes** till now.

So maybe it's the quality and the relevance of the content of your posts which lead to downvotes.

Comment: yes, that i would agree. i don't know if he is one or they are different. but if they don't leave comment what should i take out of it

Comment: @Amit downvotes are here and will be always here ... if you are here to avoid downvotes or you don't like them so maybe this website is not for you ... honestly you should focus on the content and quality and helping people and also learning, don't pay attention to *free* downvotes

Answer (score 2):

**As the legit question is :**

Why are downvoters not AT LEAST commenting to let me an hint to how could my answer be improved, why is it bad at all?

**The answer is** :

It's true that commenting is encouraged when downvoting, but it's not forced; some voters would rater not identify themselves or interfere in any other way so they don't have to deal with OP arguing. Not that the OP would automatically argue in such a situation, but some won't take this chance.

Comment: just an idea : anonymous commenting should be there , no !

Comment: @Amit and we will open the way to spamming ...

Comment: yeah. thats true

Comment: "anonymous commenting" privilege for 1,000 rep user only ? with comment being anonymous for everyone except moderators to prevent rude commenting ? Just an idea.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I think that an "anonymous commenting" privilege has been suggested already, but I'm not sure. If you don't find a dupe, maybe you could make a feature request.

Comment: @DavyM Well... there is a bunch of thing i would like SO dev team to implemented before that, so... If you think it's an interesting feature request, I'll let you post it on META